# How can I populate a form from an ng-repeat item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to click on an ng-repeat ed row in a table and populate a form from the rows data. What do I need to have in my editplayer() function?

Heres the table and the form

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="player in players" ng-model="players">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""></td>
        <td ng-click="editPlayer($index)">{{ player.name }}</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<form id="playerForm" name="playerForm" ng-model="thisplayer" novalidate>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="id"  placeholder="id" class="form-control" ng-model="player.id" ></input>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="player" name="name"  required placeholder="Name" class="form-control" ng-model="player.name" ng-required="true" >{{ player.name }}</input>
    <span ng-show="playerForm.name.$touched && playerForm.newplayer.name.$invalid">The name is required.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" id="email"  required Placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="player.email">{{ player.email }}    </input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="tel"  required Placeholder="Tel" class="form-control" ng-model="player.tel">{{ player.tel }}</input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="initials"  required Placeholder="Initials" class="form-control" ng-model="player.initials">{{ player.initials }}</input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="btnPlayerAdd" name="btnPlayerAdd" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="addPlayer($event)" ng-show="!isUpdate">Add player</button>
    <button id="btnPlayerSave" name="btnPlayerSave" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="updatePlayer($event)" ng-show="isUpdate">Update player</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your controller? That is where you would define `editPlayer`, `players`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
        <td>{{player.Name}}</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="editplayer(player)" /></td>

    </tr>
```

And in editplayer() :

```
$scope.editplayer= function (player) {
        $scope.player.id = player.Id;
        $scope.player.name = player.Name;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `editPlayer(player)`.

Assuming `editPlayer` populates the form, just pass it the `player` object.